# How can I display the vocabulary description?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a View which displays content by taxonomy term from a particular vocabulary, and everything is going fine... except for one thing. I would like to display the Vocabulary description in the View header. I have succeeded in doing this by creating an attachment in the View which just does a select on the Vocabulary but this seems to me rather cumbersome and I wondered if there is a better way to do it.

Also, although I have succeeded in attaching my Attachment to the main Page in the View, I cannot see any way of controlling the order in which they appear. As it happens, things appear in the order I want but it seems to be more by accident than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

An `attachment` is the cleanest way to do this using the Views Admin UI. Attachments can be re-ordered in the region they are placed in the parent view.

Another way to do this which requires code is to use `hook_views_pre_view()` and to create a blank `Views Header Area` in your views admin area -- then in code via `hook_views_pre_view()` set the content of that area using PHP to the description of your taxonomy term. But I would recommend trying to stick to the Views Admin for creating your views, as the more custom code you put in files/modules the harder your site is to maintain or change.

Comment: Thanks and I agree with your comment on avoiding special code. In fact I realised after I posted the question that once an attachment has been added to a page display, you can edit the attachment parameters so that it appears before the page display, after it, or both.

Answer (score 0):

```
function YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME() {

  $vocabulary = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
  $checklist_vocab_array = array(); /* Change to array('0' => '--none--'); if you want a none option*/
  foreach ($vocabulary as $item) {
  $key = $item->vid;
  $value = $item->name;
  $checklist_vocab_array[$key] = $value;
  }

  $form['YOUR_MODULE_NAME_YOUR_FORM_NAME'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'checkboxes',
    '#title'            => t('List of current Vocabularies.'),
    '#position'         => 'left' ,
    '#options'          => $checklist_vocab_array ,
    '#default_value'    => variable_get('YOUR_MODULE_NAME_YOUR_FORM_NAME'),
    '#description'      => t('List of vocabularies displayed as checkboxes'),
  );
     return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

for more information checkout this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_vocabularies/7.x